# Есть разница между func(1); и func('1'); в php?

Tags: php

Есть розница между `func(1);` и `func('1');` в php? например `<?php echo func(1); ?>` и `<?php echo func('1'); ?>`

Comment: Все зависит от того, как вы определите функцию.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow ммм спасибо а зависит на скорость?

Comment: это не то место, где надо думать о скорости, если в коде функции вам не нужен тип переменной, то можете хоть как передавать параметры

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разница есть. `func(1);` - типом переменной будет **integer**, `func('1');` в этом случае, переменная передаваемая в функцию будет иметь тип **string**. Если вас не интересует тип переменной, то никакой разницы нет. Если разница во времени обработки и есть, то она мизерная

Comment: Спасибо вам....

Comment: @KYRAN, благодарность можно выразить поставив плюс моему ответу, и отметив его галочкой, как правильный)